# SuiteCRM setting initial_filter of the aos_products popup

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I need to add a custom filter to the `aos_products` popup where you can choose the line items from the `aos_quotes` edit view.
What the filter should look like is `equal to WHERE aos_procucts_cstm.remaining_capacity_c > 0`.

What I have so far is in editviewdefs.php of the aos_product module:

```
array(
'name' => 'remaining_capacity_c',
'label' => 'LBL_RESTKAPAZITAET',
   'displayParams' =>
     array(
       'initial_filter' => array(
         '&remaining_capacity_c > 0',
         ),
       ),
     ),
```

but this does not work as intended. I believe that it is not possible to set up the filter like I did. So any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Following below steps:

1. `remaining_capacity_c` needs to be a field type that where you can "Enable Range Search" in studio. So I would suggest using "Integer" type in this case.
2. Second, you will need to add the field into the popup search definition.
3. you will need to set the variables required to do a range search.

Example:

```
'initial_filter' => array(
    '&remaining_capacity_c_advanced_range_choice=greater_than&range_remaining_capacity_c_advanced=0&start_range_remaining_capacity_c_advanced=&end_remaining_range_capacity_c_advanced=',
 ),
```

EDIT

You can use the keys found in **date_range_search_dom dropdown**. just set the **[fieldname]_advanced_range_choice** to one of the keys and **range_[fieldname]_advanced** to the value you wish to compare. When you wish to edit the start and end. You need to specify the **start_range_[fieldname]_advanced** and **end_range_[fieldname]_advanced** values.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same question as the guy above.
So, if the field is set to have "Enable Range Search", you can automatically add greater_than, and it works?
Because I need greater than on one field, and less than on another field for AOS_Products Popup search.

Comment: Thank you so much. And just one more thing - should it be added in editviewdefs, or popupviewdefs?

Comment: I've just figured out it doesn't work in Products Popups, because Products Popup in, for an example, Quotes, doesn't have range choice dropdown. Is there a way for range to be enabled in popups?